# My DevExpress Grid not sort and filter data (MVC 4.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

I have one page with a Devexpress GridView where I want to show all my table data (using Entity Framework).

On the first page load all data is shown however my Devexpress GridView don't sort and filter. :(

Below is my code :

**My controller**

```
public class MenuController : Controller
    {
        private AcessoEntities db = new AcessoEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var menu = db.MENU.Include(m => m.MENU2);
            return View(menu.ToList());
        }
}
```

This is my View :

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
        s =>
        {
            s.Name = "Lista";
            s.KeyFieldName = "Id";

            s.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;

            s.Columns.Add("Nome");
            s.Columns.Add("MENU2.Nome", "Meu pai").SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Ascending;
            s.Columns.Add("Ordem_Menu", "Ordem menu");

        }).BindToLINQ(string.Empty, string.Empty, (s, e) =>
        {
            var data = new Hoya.Extranet.Interface.Models.AcessoEntities();
            e.QueryableSource = data.MENU;
        }).GetHtml()
```

When I click to sort or filter it just shows a image "Loading" and nothing happens...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you got success with my example ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a partial view specifically for that GridView so that the Grid can Callback to get server data. And for that you need to have an ActionResult for that GridView.

So do the following :

Create a Partial View and put your GridView Code inside.

You need to define also a callback route to that GridView using something like this (inside your gridview definitions):

```
settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "MenuController", Action = "YourPartialView" };
```

And my personal advice is that you should pass data to the PartialView using the View Model concept.

You can also see a good example of that here : http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/Sorting